# How to publish a .NET Core application in English only?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I publish my app with the following command: `dotnet publish -c Debug -r linux-arm`.  It works fine, however, it generates folders for languages I don't need.

There are these 3 files in each folder: Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll, Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll, System.Spatial.resources.dll.

I do not use these DLLs at all.

Furthermore, the language folders are not there if I publish for Windows.  Only for Linux-arm.

How do I just limit the publish to English?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any other dependencies that might be introducing localization? I just tested that exact same command on one of my ASP.NET Core MVC projects without getting any of the localized folders. Maybe something like a Telerik or DevExpress would introduce those?

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett I just checked and the languages only appear if I publish for linux-arm.  If I publish for Windows, the languages are not there.  I also updated the question to list the files that are in the folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net Core exclude published language directories other than english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330650/asp-net-core-exclude-published-language-directories-other-than-english)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer [MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#satelliteresourcelanguages)

Add the line `<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en-US</SatelliteResourceLanguages>` in to the property group in your project file. For example,

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en-US</SatelliteResourceLanguages> 
   </PropertyGroup>
```