# ASP.Net Core exclude published language directories other than english

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I publish my ASP.Net Core 3.1 Server like this:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win7-x64 -p:PublishTrimmed=true --output c:\MyServer
```

What I get in c:\MyServer is a lot of international language directories: cs, de, es, fr, zh-hans etc

How can I publish with only the English version ?

I tried using `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment` in my csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>    
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>inprocess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>cs;de;es;fr;he;hi;it;ja;ko;nl;pl;pt;ru;tr-TR;zh-Hans;zh-Hant</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But that didn't help

Any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.net core build produces localization folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424796/net-core-build-produces-localization-folders)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Edit your .csproj and add the following line to a PropertyGroup:

```
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

It should publish only the selected language resource folder.

Comment: Refer MSBuild properties - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#satelliteresourcelanguages

Comment: This helps to limit the language folders, but not get rid of them altogether.

Answer (score 20):

You get a lot of language folders containing `CodeAnalysis.dll` files in your published output if you have a project reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`, which is needed for scaffolding controllers. If that is true for your project, change the package reference in your .csproj file to include ExcludeAssets="All":

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" ExcludeAssets="All"/>
```

Refer to https://forums.asp.net/t/2160546.aspx?how+to+get+rid+of+fr+it+ja+etc+folders+in+net+core+3+0+

Comment: FYI - This works for me in preventing the localization folders, but it breaks scaffolding. (Core 3.1). I have to remove the [ExcludeAssets=All] directive and build the project each time if I choose to use scaffolding to build views, etc..

Comment: This wasn't helpful to me from some reason.

Comment: Still valid in .NET 7.0.